# How does one set persistent instance variables on ActiveRecord objects without an identity map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been knocking my head against a problem for ages until I realised what was going on.

I want to have a committee which must always have at least one member. To achieve this, each member checks it's not the last member before being destroyed.

The code below should prevent the last member being destroyed UNLESS the committee itself is being destroyed in which case it happily self-destructs.

```
class Committee < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :committee_members
  before_destroy: { @destroy_initiated = true }

  def destroy_initiated?
    @destroy_initiated
  end

end

class CommitteeMember < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :committee
  before_destroy :ensure_not_last

  def ensure_not_last
    unless self.committee.destroy_initiated?
      if self.committee.committee_members.count == 1
        raise 'You cannot remove the last committe member. Try destroying the committee instead'
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**The problem**

The problem is that each CommitteeMember references a different instance of the Committee object, they all have different object identities:

e.g. `#<Committee:0x00000105c41f20>` v. `#<Committee:0x00000105c2c3a0>`

This means that even when I set @destroy_initiated to be true on once instance of Committee with ID 20, it's not going to be set to true on the instance referenced by one of its committee_members.

Leaving aside Rails 3.1 which I know has an identity map, is there a clean workaround to having an instance variable which is available on all instantiations of Committee?

I'm considering doing a class variable containing a map of destroy_initiated? to each Committee ID but this feels pretty messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I can answer this question properly without more context, but I can give you a possible solution to think about...

In an app I just recently put in production, we would essentially cache an object as an instance variable on ApplicationController. Then whenever we needed it, we simply ask for the instance variable rather than finding it with Active Record.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_committee

  def set_committee
    @committee ||= Committee.new()
  end
end
```

So now, for the duration of the request, anything inheriting from ApplicationController can access the @committee object. If you can use a similar pattern (doesn't have to be application controller, could just be any other controller) you would essentially have a "global" variable for the duration of the request.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - it's reassuring to see that I'm not the only one thinking about this. I like the approach you've taken and wonder if one wanted a more namespaced approach you could even store a mapping of objects as a class variable on the CommitteeMember class so that you could reference a particular member instance by CommitteeMember.instances[committee_member_id]. Either way, thanks for the input.